# Cannot call a server-side function located inside a library from client-side code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I tried the simplest way of calling Google Apps Script server-side function from my html using the sample code given here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run. It works like a charm.

However, when I try to do the same thing in my actual project which has all the server code in a **library**, it doesn't work. I keep getting the error

> "**Uncaught TypeError: google.script.run.doSomething is not a function**"

Here is a sample project that I created to recreate the issue

[**The Gdoc**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lrqqHVSBgv7vz-d6OJha4R53CU2ORLFjXu1buvKWVhk/edit)
Here look for "Test Menu" and click on "open sidebar" to invoke the functionality. Access the **bound script** to see the code and the usage of Library.

[**Library code**](https://script.google.com/a/devfactory.com/d/1HA45LtZm1yqX-fSTZ0khIPq-4WGo4FpgvqyhF0pPaKc4f8eauvDo2oNI/edit)

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: it is really hard to help you without any assist of you, could you share the project which is not working? can you share the relevant piece of code ? (for example for me it's unclear what you mean by "in my project / all the code in a library" are you talking about a local project or something?)

Comment: @CrissCrossCrass edited the post with all details. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I assume you realize that `google.script.run.doSomething` should be `google.script.run.doSomething()`.

Comment: Yes, I do. If you open my project, you will see that's how I have coded.

Comment: When using the `google.script.run` API, only public methods of your server-side script are exposed. If you want to reference library methods, then I believe you need a public wrapper for them: `function useLib() { return myLibName.doSomething(); }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Library function from html with google.script.run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928932/call-library-function-from-html-with-google-script-run)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352328/server-error-google-script-run-fails-when-using-a-shared-library

Answer (score 0):

Example:

html:

```
<script>
function doSomething() {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(msg){
    window.alert(msg);//Thank's I got it.
  })
  .doSomething();
} 
</script>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Do Something" onClick="doSomething();" />
</body>
```

gs:

```
function doSomething() {
  return 'Thanks I got it';
}
```

Comment: If I copy paste this stuff directly in the script bound to the doc, then all works fine. My problem is when I put this code in the library and then invoke it from my script bound to the doc then it doesn't. I see, the issue is something to do with me using the library, but I don't know what it is and how can I resolve it... When I say library, I mean this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

Comment: Are you adding the library name before the function?

Comment: can you please precisely tell which function are you talking about? From the bound script all library functions that I call are prefixed with the library name.

Comment: I've never tried to access library code using google.script.run.

Answer (score 0):

### You are trying to call `DocumentApp.getUi()` from the library.

As you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getui)

> A script can only interact with the UI for the current instance of an
>   open document, and only if the script is bound to the document.

Your library is not bound to your document. This is why your code cannot work.

You can only move those parts of your code into a library that do no use `getUi()` or any `Not-shared resources` (e.g. triggers). The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#creating_a_library) specifies which resources are shared and which ones are not.

Comment: I don't agree. I have used DocumentApp.getUi() at many places in my other project and it works just fine

Comment: You mean you have DocumentApp.getUi() implemented in a library and could access it from a script into which you incorporated this library? I tried to do this before posting my answer and found that it was not possible - at least for the creation of sidebars.