# Google Sheets Private Add-on: can't use library

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to deploy an internal Editor Add-on I wrote in App Script. I successfully deployed a test add-on and installed it, it appears in Google Sheets Extensions menu.

In this add-on, I want to use a helper library (that I wrote) which contains most of the logic. The Add-on contains UI-related code, and calls functions declared in the library.

My problem is that the add-on does not load when I declare the library, the menu is empty:
[image]

In the add-on logs, it appears as "failed":
[image]

It may be related to the way the helper library is shared/imported but I can't see what's wrong.

It works perfectly if I use the add-on code as plain app script.

Thanks for your help!

### Edit

This is due to the fact that I used a library in development mode (HEAD). It does not seem to be documented.
Thanks to @jan for this message: [Server error, google.script.run fails when using a shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352328/server-error-google-script-run-fails-when-using-a-shared-library/65507220#65507220)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766876/how-do-you-use-an-external-javascript-library-in-a-google-apps-addon-script

Comment: Are you using Card Service or Sidebars in your Sheet Add-on?

Comment: hello, it's an Editor Add-on, I'm using SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu if that's what you ask?
It's not only related to the menu, custom functions do not work either.
The thing is that onOpen fails and does not write in logs (first line is Logger.log("enter onOpen")). Even in GC logs manager I don't see this line.
It's like everything fails because of the library.